# All Both of Them?

Tags: is-it-a-rule

Recently, I was in a conversation with my friend about pool balls while playing a game. In the conversation he referred to knocking in his last two balls as, "I just hit all both of them in." When I heard this I was immediately confused on whether or not is statement was grammatically correct. Is it appropriate to say, "All both of them?"

Comment: It's not idiomatic.  Typically a statement such as that is due to a person "editing" his speech in-flight.  Eg, he started to say "I just hit all of them in" but decided late that "both" was the better term.  But he failed to tell his mouth to not say "all", which was already in the "pipeline".

Comment: I could be dialect, although I can't say that I've heard it.  Bear in mind that in (southern) parts of the US the second person plural pronoun is, colloquially, "All y'all."

Answer (score 2):

- **All both of them*

is wrong for the same reason that

- **all two of them*

is wrong (asterisks denote ungrammaticality, btw).

I.e, *both* already **means** **all two* (a phrase that doesn't occur in English;
*both* is a suppletive form for a nonexistent phrase, like *ever* for **anywhen*, and *went* for **goed*).

And **all both* doesn't exist, either; it's as ungrammatical as **all all three*.
Except as a joke among native speakers, which is true of practically any misspeak.

Comment: The example All two of them isn't wrong, because two refers to what's contained in all. Just an FYI.

Same like all too soon, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While superfluous, a missing , can help the sentence be valid. As is though, it's grammatically incorrect, as both all and both pertain to the two balls.
Redundancy isn't valid in these cases, unless they are adjectives listed before a subject.

Then, if we add the comma, it can be two *incomplete* sentences joined. "I just hit all"(fragment) and ", both of them in"(another fragment).

**Yes, technically speaking the sentence as is, is incorrect.**